# no-explicit-any issue with typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm still learning typescript. I have the following code

```
 const callWithRetry = retry(dcxAsset.copy.bind(dcxAsset), {
      maxAttempts: 3, // make up to 10 attempts
      delay: 500, // in milliseconds
      // only retry if the error has a statusCode property set to 503
      shouldRetry: (err: any) => this.shouldRetry(err.statusCode)
 });
```

Typescript has an issue with me using the type any on the line where I have the shouldRetry function. So I have to use
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any -- Allow this to assign variable to any */ to disable the error. How can I address the error without having to use eslint?

I get the error: `ESLint: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.(@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)`

Comment: What kind of issue you have?
I tried with this and worked without issue (i just declared a test "retry" function)

`function retry(param:{maxAttempts:number,delay:number,shouldRetry: (err:any) => void}){
    console.log(param.maxAttempts);
    console.log(param.delay);
    param.shouldRetry({statusCode:503})
};

const callWithRetry = retry({
    maxAttempts: 3, // make up to 10 attempts
    delay: 500, // in milliseconds
    // only retry if the error has a statusCode property set to 503
    shouldRetry: (err:any) => console.log(err.statusCode)
});`

Comment: I get the error: ESLint: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.(@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)

Comment: Well, shouldn't `err` be the parent type `Error`?

Comment: I tried that but that fails. Is there a way to cast it to a specific object with statusCode as a parameter?